# Auth0 - get normalized profile from userinfo after login

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0, auth0

I'm using the Auth0 PHP client, and I'm successfully getting calling the `$auth0->getUser()` endpoint. The way the data is coming in now, I need to parse the data to determine which idP is being used. Ideally, I could get the normalized data and not have to parse the data received!

Is there a way to get normalized profile information after a user logs in?

Sample responses from 2 different idP:

```
g-suite
{
  "sub": "google-apps|john.doe@sample.com",
  "given_name": "John",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "nickname": "john.doe",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/fdsaf32fewfdsfsaf",
  "locale": "en",
  "updated_at": "2019-09-06T19:52:28.375Z"
}
```

-

```
azure:
{
  "sub": "waad|fasdjfdajdklasfjdsla",
  "given_name": "John",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "nickname": "john.doe@sample.com",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/fdsaf34ffd.png",
  "updated_at": "2019-09-11T23:30:01.941Z"
}
```

In order to get the email address from g-suite, I need to parse the `sub`; to get the email address from azure, it's `nickname`. Normalized data would be very helpful here.

Comment: Looks there is already normalization included. https://auth0.com/docs/users/concepts/overview-user-profile#data-normalization https://auth0.com/docs/users/normalized/auth0 https://auth0.com/docs/users/normalized/auth0/normalized-user-profile-schema   You can also go to https://community.auth0.com/ as the community forum is frequently monitored.  Just my views.

Comment: Yes, I see that normalization is included, but it requires a separate API request to user search. I'd love to get normalized response as part of the sdk `getUser` call.

Comment: Custom Claims through rules can help in this case. https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims#custom-claims

Comment: Thank you @Baskar. I've opened a ticket in the Auth0 community as well:
https://community.auth0.com/t/return-normalized-profile-for-getuser-call-of-php-sdk/30808